# Android Studio requiring layout_width/height within <wallpaper> tag

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, live-wallpaper

Android studio is insisting that layout_width and layout_height are required within my  tag. I'm pretty darn sure they're not from reading [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#Wallpaper). I'm trying to figure out if this is due to some error on my part or a weird Android Studio quirk.

My layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wallpaper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:thumbnail="@drawable/icon"
android:description="@strings/description"/>
```

A snippet of my manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.handmade.tavern.LiveWallpaper"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
         android:resource="@layout/wallpaper_layout"/>
</service>
```

Has anyone else experienced this? Can anyone explain my mistake?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems that Android Studio will only allow  tags within the res/xml directory.  Simply moving the file fixed the problem. I am not sure if Android Studio is being picky or not. I have seen two references to wallpapers stored in the res/layout folder before but I don't know if they are typos. Further comments welcome.